# Derivatives of solution to Schrödinger equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

Consider the differential equation (Schrödinger, but rewritten to be pleasing to Lie algebraic eyes):

$\frac{d U(t)}{dt} = c(t)U(t)$

where $c(t)=a+w(t)b(t)$, $a,b \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$ and $w$ is a smooth real valued function of $t$.

Assuming that $U(t)$ really does solve the equation given, I'm trying to find a general formula for:

$\frac{d^n U(t)}{dt^n} \bigg|_{t=0}$

in terms of $a,b$ and the derivatives of $w$ at $t=0$ only.

The first few are easy to find, but I'm really hoping that someone can spot the pattern and get a general formula as I'm not seeing it after substantial staring!

Comment: Do the matrices $a,b$ commute?

Comment: Take the simpler case for just normal real valued functions (or your case if $[a,b]=0$) then a formula is known and reads $\frac{d^ne^{f(x)}}{dx^n} = \sum\limits_{k_1+2k_2+3k_3+\ldots nk_n = n} \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\ldots k_n!(1!^{k_1}2!^{k_2}\ldots n!^{k_n})}\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{d^if(x)}{dx^i}\right)^{k_i} e^{f(x)}$ where $k_i\in \mathbb{N}_0$. There as many different terms as there are partitions of $n$ in the sum. It's closed form, but it's not very pretty. I don't know how useful this would be in practice.

Comment: @Winter:  No, they do not commute and $w$ depends on time.